# "Memory-Hard" vs. "Memory-Bound" Functions?

Tags: proof-of-work, memory-hard

One of the approaches in order to prevent Sybil or DoS attacks is CPU-bound PoW. However, because of the influence of Moore’s law, the memory-based approaches are suggested.

As actually there are two different terms: (1) **memory-hard** functions and (2) **memory-bound** functions;

Does it mean that we have two different memory-based techniques?

And if yes, What is the difference between these two terms?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/238421/971, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84002/351, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/130244/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia definitions are clear;

- [memory-bound functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_bound_function);

  > Memory bound refers to a situation in which the time to complete a given computational problem is decided primarily by the amount of memory required to hold data.

  This is proposed for using against spams, first CPU-bound then memory bound. This algorithms requires to access memory in an unpredictable way so that caches are ineffective. This discourage the spammers.
- [memory-hard functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hard_function)

  > In cryptography, a memory hard function (MHF) is a function that costs significant amount of memory to evaluate. It is different from memory bound functions, **the latter incurs cost by slowing down computation through memory latency.** MHFs find their use as a form of proof-of-work.

  This is against the massive parallelization of hashing etc. For example the bitcoin miners create farms for SHA2d calculations since SHA2 is not memory hard.

  There are two variants

  - Data Dependent
  - Data independent

  For example [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) has both mode and even combined. Argon2i for data independent and Argon2d for data dependent. In the combined mode Argon2id.